# Apache POI - Show a numberic data starting with 0

Tags: java, excel, apache, types, apache-poi

I am creating an excel using Apache POI class. I have a column with data as 07898.

When I opened the excel the data is showing properly with 07898 with a warning message. When I click the mouse inside the excel is considering it as number and removing the 0 automatically.

But if I change the column type as text in Microsoft excel, it is not removing the 0. But I am not able to set the column type as Text. It is always Generic.

Any suggestion please let me know. Thank you. 
I am setting the type as String, but it is not working properly.

```
SXSSFWorkbook hwb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
Sheet sheet = hwb.createSheet(strReportName);
Cell excelheadercell = excelheader.createCell((short) icolumns);
excelheadercell.setCellValue("07898");
CellStyle cellstyle = hwb.createCellStyle();
Font font = hwb.createFont();
font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
cellstyle.setFont(font);
excelheadercell.setCellStyle(cellstyle);
**excelheadercell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);**
```

Comment: Have you tried HSSFWorkbook instead of SXSSFWorkbook? It says something about incompatibility issues with some clients. the excelheader how do you declare it? Can you post the code?

Comment: Why do you not just save it as the number `7898` and apply a formatting rule to it that requests 5 digits with a leading zero? That's how you'd make Excel display it, so it's just the same with POI!